# MLA8 Formatting using Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, mla-style, biblatex-mla

I am using sharelatex.com to work on a research paper for my English class, and I need to do my citations using the new MLA8 format. Some of my sources use multiple containers, so I need to express this in the bibliography too. Is there any way I can set this up? If not on sharelatex.com, how about on my desktop installation?

Comment: `biblatex-mla` supports the new version (in principle) if you specify `style=mla-new`.  Since I have no idea what you mean by "multiple containers", you would really need to provide a minimal example of what that means and how the current version doesn't handle it properly.  See [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407).

Comment: With respect to ShareLaTeX, I have no idea how up-to-date its packages are; the version that supports MLA8 is version 1.9, November 2, 2016.  I assume that if the `style=mla-new` gives you an error, then you would be better off using it on your desktop, which I assume you can make sure has the most recent version installed.

Comment: @AlanMunn The way the MLA8 citation format works is that you start by listing basic info about the source, like the author and title. You then list the containers; for example, am article might have a journal as it's container. You list the name of the container, along with other info like publisher and publication date. Sources can also have more than one container. My teacher has specified that an article from a journal found in an online database must list both the journal and the database as containers. Is there any way to implement this with BibLaTex?

Comment: The first part of what you're describing is really just normal bibliography practice, but with a term that the MLA has invented. The requirement that an article contained in a database list both is quite unusual, and I don't think most other styles use it. But `biblatex` provides the `eprint` and `eprinttype` database field entries which can be used for that purpose, and this is how the `mla-new` style does this.

Comment: @AlanMunn Do you want to attempt an answer here?

Answer (score 1):

The [`biblatex-mla`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-mla) style, specifically its `style=mla-new`, implements MLA 8th edition guidelines.

The style has received a major update last year, yet there are some entry types that are not supported, and some functionalities of the `biblatex` standard styles do not work as expected.